# Using two for loops within a javascript function javascript animation

Tags: javascript, function, loops

**Added: 12/30/14 - 7:00am(EST)
This problem has been solved**
Below I have posted a link to a jsfiddle where you can see the finished product. In addition to the rotating plus sign, I have added a div that appears off screen, and with a click of the mouse, appears onscreen. This div can be filled with content. While the aforementioned sentence would cause most on this forum to exclaim: "No duh!" I mostly included this portion for those novices who may be stumbling across this post in the next few months.  Hopefully, no one else will need to ask this question in the future.

http://jsfiddle.net/amolner/gqe4tpqs/31/
Anyone is free to use the above code for any purposes. If anyone has any ways to improve the above code above for the benefit of those finding this post in the future, please feel free to tinker with it. Again, thank you to everyone who contributed thus far. So saved me a lot of headaches.

**Original text:**
Upon the first click, everything works the way that it is supposed to. The plus sign moves 45 degrees to the right, turning it into an "x." It is upon the second click where thinks go awry. It is upon the second click that I would like the x to move backwards 45 degrees so that it turns back into a "+" sign. Instead, it starts over at 0 and moves right 45 degrees. I've been at this a so long that I am embarrassed to say just how long. I have lines and lines of failed code but I feel the following is the closest I've come. If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
    <script>
    var degrees = 0;
    function rotateAnimation(){
        for (degrees = 45; degrees > -1; degrees--){
            setTimeout(function(x){
                return function({
                    document.getElementById('thing').style.transform = "rotate("+x+"deg)";
                }
            }(degrees),-20*degrees);
        }

        for (degrees = 0; degrees < 45; degrees++){
            setTimeout(function(x){ 
                return function() {
                    document.getElementById('thing').style.transform = "rotate("+x+"deg)";
                }
            }(degrees),20*degrees);

        }
    }
    </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1 onclick="rotateAnimation();" id="thing" style="cursor:pointer;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;font-size:5em;">+</h1>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle maybe?

Comment: what you mean when try pass to `setTimeout` negative interval like `-20*degrees`?

Comment: I added the JSfiddle that Shimon was kind enough to make for me. @Grundy, the -20 was leftover from when I was just messing around. it didn't work. The relevant changes have been made and the "-" has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the condition for various degrees i.e 0,-1, and 45

```
function rotateAnimation(){
    if(degrees==45){
    for (degrees = 45; degrees > -1; degrees--){
        setTimeout(function(x){return function(){document.getElementById('thing').style.transform = "rotate("+x+"deg)";}}(degrees),20*(45-degrees));

        }
    }

        if(degrees==0  ){
    for (degrees = 0; degrees < 45; degrees++){
        setTimeout(function(x){return function(){document.getElementById('thing').style.transform = "rotate("+x+"deg)";}}(degrees),20*degrees);

        }
    }

    else if(degrees==-1){
        degrees=0;
    }

        }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RahulB007/0r9ydm1x/1/

Comment: Thank you everyone who contributed. While all the responses do work, I chose this one for its simplicity. Also, it does not require you to link to the jquery library. Once again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have put it for you in jsFiddle and fixed syntax errors: http://jsfiddle.net/4bj62s59/5/

```
<script>
    var degrees = 0;
    function rotateAnimation(){
        for (degrees = 45; degrees > -1; degrees--){
            setTimeout((function(x){
                return function(){
                    document.getElementById('thing').style.transform = "rotate("+x+"deg)";
                }
            })(degrees),-20*degrees);
        }

        for (degrees = 0; degrees < 45; degrees++){
            setTimeout((function(x){
                return function() {
                    document.getElementById('thing').style.transform = "rotate("+x+"deg)";
                }
            })(degrees),20*degrees);

        }
    }
</script>
<h1 onclick="rotateAnimation();" id="thing" style="cursor:pointer;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;font-size:5em;">+</h1>
```

here is a css solution: http://jsfiddle.net/94v95sh0/1/
using this animator: http://cssanimate.com/
first time i have generated:
end frame rotate 45 deg only 
give it a class name cross right and give it a name rotate right
second time i have generated 
start frame rotrate 45 deg
end frame rotate 0 deg 
give it a class name cross left and give it a name rotate left

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate this working. This is an example hacked together based on your existing work and can be improved in many ways, starting with code extraction and the use of [requestAnimationFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh773174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `setTimeout`

I started by avoiding redeclaring degrees at every loop so a global state can be maintained and persist, then added an if statement to check the current state of the animation. Also, passing variables into a `setTimeout` function this way is not valid javascript, although it will work in most browsers. I have changed how the data is being passed around to create valid javascript as seen below

```
var degrees = 0;
var rotateAnimation = function(){

    if (degrees == 45) {
            var spin = function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var x = degrees;
                    document.getElementById('thing').style.transform = "rotate("+x+"deg)";
                    if (degrees > 0) {
                       spin(--degrees);   
                    }
                });
            }

            spin();

    } else {            

        var spin = function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var x = degrees;
                    document.getElementById('thing').style.transform = "rotate("+x+"deg)";
                    if (degrees < 45) {
                       spin(++degrees);   
                    }
                });
            }

            spin();
        }

}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/fmL37L5f/